# Unity, First time using a script in c# it's working fine then after few times getting null exception why?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a ThirdPersonController in the Hierarchy.
Then i'm adding to it a Nav Mesh Agent.
The dragging to it the scrip in c#.
Then in the Inspector i'm adding in the script part the agent.
Then baking.

And it was working more or less with some stuttering but was working.
The character ThirdPersonController walked automatic to specific point in this case to a cylinder i have on my Terrain.

I can't figure out why first time/s it's working fine but then now i have this error.

This is the script i'm using for the automatic walk:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class BasicAi : MonoBehaviour {

    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public ThirdPersonCharacter character;

    public enum State {

        PATROL,
        CHASE
    }

    public State state;
    private bool alive;

    // Variables for patrolling
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    private int waypointInd = 0;
    public float patrolSpeed = 0.5f;


    // Variable for chasing
    public float chaseSpeed = 1f;
    public GameObject target;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
        character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();

        agent.updatePosition = true;
        agent.updateRotation = false;

        state = BasicAi.State.PATROL;

        alive = true;

        StartCoroutine ("FSM");

    }

    IEnumerator FSM()
    {
        while (alive)
        {
            switch (state)
            {

            case State.PATROL:
                Patrol ();
                break;
            case State.CHASE:
                Chase ();
                break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void Patrol()
    {
        agent.speed = patrolSpeed;

        if (Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, waypoints [waypointInd].transform.position) >= 2) {

            agent.SetDestination (waypoints [waypointInd].transform.position);
            character.Move (agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
        } else if (Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, waypoints [waypointInd].transform.position) <= 2) {
            waypointInd += 1;
            if (waypointInd > waypoints.Length) {
                waypointInd = 0;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            character.Move (Vector3.zero, false, false);
        }
    }

    void Chase()
    {
        agent.speed = chaseSpeed;
        agent.SetDestination (target.transform.position);
        character.Move (agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.tag == "Player") 
        {
            state = BasicAi.State.CHASE;
            target = coll.gameObject;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
```

And the exception error message is:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonCharacter.CheckGroundStatus () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonCharacter.cs:215)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonCharacter.Move (Vector3 move, Boolean crouch, Boolean jump) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonCharacter.cs:54)
BasicAi.Patrol () (at Assets/My Scripts/BasicAi.cs:72)
BasicAi+<FSM>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/My Scripts/BasicAi.cs:55)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String)
BasicAi:Start() (at Assets/My Scripts/BasicAi.cs:43)
```

When i click on the error message in the Console window it's going to the ThirdPersonCharacter script. The script is from in Unity.

The error is on the line:

```
m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
```

And this is the ThirdPersonCharacter script where the error is:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    public class ThirdPersonCharacter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
        [SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
        [SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
        [Range(1f, 4f)][SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
        [SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
        [SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        [SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        [SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;

        Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
        Animator m_Animator;
        bool m_IsGrounded;
        float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
        const float k_Half = 0.5f;
        float m_TurnAmount;
        float m_ForwardAmount;
        Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
        float m_CapsuleHeight;
        Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
        CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
        bool m_Crouching;


        void Start()
        {
            m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
            m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
            m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

            m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
            m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;
        }


        public void Move(Vector3 move, bool crouch, bool jump)
        {

            // convert the world relative moveInput vector into a local-relative
            // turn amount and forward amount required to head in the desired
            // direction.
            if (move.magnitude > 1f) move.Normalize();
            move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
            CheckGroundStatus();
            move = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(move, m_GroundNormal);
            m_TurnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z);
            m_ForwardAmount = move.z;

            ApplyExtraTurnRotation();

            // control and velocity handling is different when grounded and airborne:
            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                HandleGroundedMovement(crouch, jump);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleAirborneMovement();
            }

            ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(crouch);
            PreventStandingInLowHeadroom();

            // send input and other state parameters to the animator
            UpdateAnimator(move);
        }


        void ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(bool crouch)
        {
            if (m_IsGrounded && crouch)
            {
                if (m_Crouching) return;
                m_Capsule.height = m_Capsule.height / 2f;
                m_Capsule.center = m_Capsule.center / 2f;
                m_Crouching = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
                float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
                if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
                {
                    m_Crouching = true;
                    return;
                }
                m_Capsule.height = m_CapsuleHeight;
                m_Capsule.center = m_CapsuleCenter;
                m_Crouching = false;
            }
        }

        void PreventStandingInLowHeadroom()
        {
            // prevent standing up in crouch-only zones
            if (!m_Crouching)
            {
                Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
                float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
                if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
                {
                    m_Crouching = true;
                }
            }
        }


        void UpdateAnimator(Vector3 move)
        {
            // update the animator parameters
            m_Animator.SetFloat("Forward", m_ForwardAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            m_Animator.SetFloat("Turn", m_TurnAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            m_Animator.SetBool("Crouch", m_Crouching);
            m_Animator.SetBool("OnGround", m_IsGrounded);
            if (!m_IsGrounded)
            {
                m_Animator.SetFloat("Jump", m_Rigidbody.velocity.y);
            }

            // calculate which leg is behind, so as to leave that leg trailing in the jump animation
            // (This code is reliant on the specific run cycle offset in our animations,
            // and assumes one leg passes the other at the normalized clip times of 0.0 and 0.5)
            float runCycle =
                Mathf.Repeat(
                    m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime + m_RunCycleLegOffset, 1);
            float jumpLeg = (runCycle < k_Half ? 1 : -1) * m_ForwardAmount;
            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                m_Animator.SetFloat("JumpLeg", jumpLeg);
            }

            // the anim speed multiplier allows the overall speed of walking/running to be tweaked in the inspector,
            // which affects the movement speed because of the root motion.
            if (m_IsGrounded && move.magnitude > 0)
            {
                m_Animator.speed = m_AnimSpeedMultiplier;
            }
            else
            {
                // don't use that while airborne
                m_Animator.speed = 1;
            }
        }


        void HandleAirborneMovement()
        {
            // apply extra gravity from multiplier:
            Vector3 extraGravityForce = (Physics.gravity * m_GravityMultiplier) - Physics.gravity;
            m_Rigidbody.AddForce(extraGravityForce);

            m_GroundCheckDistance = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y < 0 ? m_OrigGroundCheckDistance : 0.01f;
        }


        void HandleGroundedMovement(bool crouch, bool jump)
        {
            // check whether conditions are right to allow a jump:
            if (jump && !crouch && m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Grounded"))
            {
                // jump!
                m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(m_Rigidbody.velocity.x, m_JumpPower, m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
                m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
            }
        }

        void ApplyExtraTurnRotation()
        {
            // help the character turn faster (this is in addition to root rotation in the animation)
            float turnSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(m_StationaryTurnSpeed, m_MovingTurnSpeed, m_ForwardAmount);
            transform.Rotate(0, m_TurnAmount * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }


        public void OnAnimatorMove()
        {
            // we implement this function to override the default root motion.
            // this allows us to modify the positional speed before it's applied.
            if (m_IsGrounded && Time.deltaTime > 0)
            {
                Vector3 v = (m_Animator.deltaPosition * m_MoveSpeedMultiplier) / Time.deltaTime;

                // we preserve the existing y part of the current velocity.
                v.y = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y;
                m_Rigidbody.velocity = v;
            }
        }


        void CheckGroundStatus()
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            // helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance));
#endif
            // 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
            // it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
            {
                m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
                m_IsGrounded = true;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your `Animator` object is being disposed of during execution.

Comment: Why not paste the line of code that is causing that exception?

Comment: @Programmer you right sorry. I fixed my question with the line make the error. And the ThirdPersonCharacter script. I will put it here also the line that make the error: m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true; it's in the second script in my question, the script ThirdPersonCharacter that come with Unity.

Comment: I really don't know what's causing this but looks like Animator `m_Animator` is null. Please check when running your program and see if the Animator attached to the GameObject is destroyed or not. That's likely the problem.

Comment: The problem is with the BasicAi script once i remove it from the ThirdPersonController everything i fine i can move my character with the W S A D keys no problems and the animator is not null. So i wonder where can i find a good tutorial to make a simple automatic walking player from point to point ? No ot mvoe an object automatic but to make the character walk automatic like using the keys W S A D but automatic ? The script BasicAi i took from youtube tutorial but i guess something is wrong.